# Laravel - add a class attribute to array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Eloquent Model I have added a class attribute:

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function getIsViewable()
{
    return $this->isViewable;
}
```

This attribute is not saved in the database as it is just a computed value.

In my controller I have an Eloquent Collection of this object which I convert to an array:

```
$images = $query->get();
$images = $images->toArray();
```

How can I add the class attribute property to each image item in the array?

Comment: Maybe https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Method should be named `getMyVariableAttribute` ie. `getIsViewableAttribute`
2. On the model add the following `protected $appends = ['is_viewable']` in order to get the computed property when serializing.

Answer (score 1):

Your method name is missing the `Attribute` part. Rename `getIsViewable()` to `getIsViewableAttribute()`

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function getIsViewableAttribute()
{
    return $this->isViewable;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor